# The $c_0$ term in a Laurent expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Is the $c_0$ term part of the principal part of a Laurent series, analytic part (positive powers in $z$) or neither or both?

I am working on a problem, where I have to match up some coefficients, but am not sure what to do with the $c_0$ term.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @MikeMiller :-)

Comment: Sure! Can you remind me what principal part means here?

Comment: Hi @MikeMiller, sure - the principal part is the part of the Laurent series with all the negative power terms in $z$, or more generally $(z-z_0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a function $$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n z^n,$$ holomorphic in a neighborhood of (but not at!) $0$, as you say, we can write it as the sum of the analytic part and a completely non-analytic part. The key point is that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ *is* analytic at $0$, whereas not a single term in $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} c_n z^n$ is analytic. So this is the preferred way to split the sum, as far as I know.

If you have a more specific question about the problem you're looking at, I'm glad to answer it.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much @MikeMiller.  I solved for the coefficients to get my desired Laurent series and then took the real part of it, which is known to be harmonic in the annular domain of analyticity.  I guess a more specific question would be:  is this harmonic function unique?  I am guessing that it must be, due to the uniqueness of the Laurent coefficients.  However, a solution that I am comparing my work to says instead that the uniqueness comes from the maximum principle for harmonic functions.  What do you think?  (I also just asked this as a new question on MSE.)  Thanks so much